# How to I access the template that DotNetNuke uses when creating new pages?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I recently applied a new skin to one of our existing DotNetNuke CE sites. The upgrade of the site worked, but when I add a brand new page (not imported) to the site there are some issues.

DotNetNuke attempts to copy content from my Slogan Pane, and Top Pane when I add a new page. However, it creates multiple copies of each (about 25 of each module in each Pane). I then have to take my new TabID, go into the TabModules table, and manually delete the duplicate rows to get the new page correct.

I am sure there is a template file somewhere that DotNetNuke is utilizing to create new pages. I hope to be able to modify this file to stop the problem or point DNN to a different file to use for default page creation. Does anyone happen to know where this template is? Barring that, is there any way to interrupt/modify the new page process (without source code mod) to fix the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Templates are stored in the Portals/# folder, where # is the ID of the folder. They can be within ANY folder inside of there, so you might have to dig around a little bit.

I would guess that you perhaps created a page template, and it has the 25 modules in it, but you also have those modules set to "display on all pages" so that is where the duplication comes from.

Comment: Yes, that jogs my memory a bit. I created the new site in a test environment first so the powers that be could approve it before going live. In that test environment I had the Slogan Pane content module set to display on all pages. When the time came to move to production i used export/import method for the pages instead of recreating everything from scratch. So the display on all pages must now be actually on every page so the new pages have them all as duplicates. I think I may have to go in a uncheck that option for all existing pages except one to fix. Does that sound right?

Comment: Go to a SINGLE page, uncheck the Display on All Pages option. That should remove it from EVERY page except for that one page.

Comment: I am having success, but I am having to disable the option on every page. When I un-check one it only affects that one page. I am looking in the 'Added to Pages' setting where it should list a bunch of pages, but it doesn't have this list. I was hoping to find the setting in the database so I could write a query but I have not had luck with that yet. So lesson learned, but I might be looking at a lot of manual un-checking to fix this problem. Thanks for the help!